# SAS where condition exact matching

Tags: sas, where-clause, exact-match

Thanks for the feedback guys, but I have to rewrite the question to make it more clear.

Say, we have a table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVxyt.png)

What I am trying to get from this table is a list of numbers which have matching FP_NDT dates to my condition, for example, I want to get a list of numbers, which only have FP_NDT not null for 2014 and 2015 and missing values for 2011, 2012 and 2013 (irrelevant of the months). So with this condition I should get only Number 4. Is it possible to do it from this table ?

PS: If I write a simple sql select statement and put a condition like

```
where year(FP_NDT) in (2014,2015)
```

it would also give me numbers 2 and 3...

Comment: It is easier to test if you paste your data as text instead taking a picture of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not first summarize the data?

```
proc sql;
  create table XX as
    select number
         , max(year(fp_ndt)=2011) as yr2011
         , max(year(fp_ndt)=2012) as yr2012
         , max(year(fp_ndt)=2013) as yr2013
         , max(year(fp_ndt)=2014) as yr2014
         , max(year(fp_ndt)=2015) as yr2015
    from table1
    group by number
  ;
```

Now it is easy to make your tests.

```
  select * from XX 
    where yr2014+yr2015=2 and yr2011+yr2012+yr2013=0
  ;
```

You could use the first query as a sub-query instead of creating a physical table.

Answer (score 0):

So you want names associate with both 1 and 2 and 3, but in different rows.

You can group rows by names and count the associated numbers as this:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE xxx AS SELECT 
           name, 
           SUM(number=1) AS count1,
           SUM(number=2) AS count2,
           SUM(number=3) AS count3
    FROM test GROUP BY name;
QUIT;
```

Then you can filter the results based on count1-count3, i.e. `(count1>0 AND count2>0 AND count3>0)`.

Comment: Thanks, this one makes sense, but when the aggregate is important, say I want to have 2 missing within last 5 years. Unfortunately, it does not help to find whether I need exactly previous and the one before previous missing...

Comment: Actually it does the same as the answer with max(). Sorry for didn't noticing it earlier and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
select *
from work.test
group by name having nmiss(number)=0;
quit;
```

Comment: I actually need to get in the result a name which has certain numbers and certain missing for other numbers... For example, from the last table how can I select just Luk? I could probably do it the same way you suggested if the order of missing variables did not matter, but unfortunately it does. In this example I particularly need 3 to be missing for Luk while having 1 and 2 not null...

Answer (score 0):

I have found one work around which is to actually create separate data sets for each year and then inner join them with a where condition for missing and not null for needed years. However, it becomes a bit cumbersome when it comes to 60 months, for instance...